# What are the conditions for the covariances of a multivariate gaussian?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

For a 3 dimensional multivariate gaussian I have 3 + 3 + 3 free variables, in the mean, the standard deviation and the covariances. For simplicity we assume a standardized multivariate gaussian (mean = 0, standard deviation = 1). If I know two of the three covariances, $\rho_{12}$ and $\rho_{13}$, what can I say about $\rho_{23}$?

I presume that there would be more or less simple inequalities about maximum and minimum values for $\rho_{23}$. However, the only thing I can come up with is solving for positive definitenes, which is kind of complicated.

Additionally, how would this inequality change if I change the dimension of the gaussian?

Comment: As long as the covariance matrix is positive definite you'll have a non degenerate multivariate normal distribution.  For the $n=3$ case you can write out conditions for positive definiteness in terms of the known covariances and variances.  For larger values of $n$, semidefinite programming can be used.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Yes, I thought so, but are those conditions somehow simple/understandable?

Comment: For small values of $n$ (2 or 3) you can use the condition that the leading principal minor determinants have to be positive.  This gives you polynomial inequalities.  More generally you can use a semidefinite programming solver.

Comment: For a trivariate normal $N_3(\mathbf 0, \Sigma)$ where $\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix}1&\rho_{12}&\rho_{13}\\\rho_{12}&1&\rho_{23}\\\rho_{13}&\rho_{23}&1\end{pmatrix} $, the condition seems to be simply $\det\Sigma\ge 0 \implies 1+2\rho_{12}\rho_{13}\rho_{23}\ge \rho_{12}^2+\rho_{13}^2+\rho_{23}^2$. If the correlations are all equal to $\rho$ (say), then [we have](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/72790/119261) $\rho\in [-\frac12,1]$ in this special case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the covariance matrix to be positive semidefinite.

As StubbornAtom says, if the covariance matrix is $\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix}1&\rho_{12}&\rho_{13}\\\rho_{12}&1&\rho_{23}\\\rho_{13}&\rho_{23}&1\end{pmatrix}$, i.e. also the correlation matrix, then this amounts to requiring $\det \Sigma \ge 0$ since all the principal minors are $1$ or $1-\rho^2_{ij} \ge 0$.

If you know $\rho_{12}$ and $\rho_{13}$ then this corresponds to an interval for $\rho_{23}$:
$$\rho_{12}\rho_{13} - \sqrt{(1-\rho_{12}^2)(1-\rho_{13}^2)} \le  \rho_{23} \le \rho_{12}\rho_{13} + \sqrt{(1-\rho_{12}^2)(1-\rho_{13}^2)}$$

This could be generalised to remove the marginal standard normal assumption,  by substituting for the correlations by using covariances and variances. Starting with $\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix}\sigma^2_1&\sigma_{12}&\sigma_{13}\\\sigma_{12}&\sigma^2_2&\sigma_{23}\\\sigma_{13}&\sigma_{23}&\sigma^2_3\end{pmatrix}$
and knowing $\sigma^2_1,\sigma^2_{2},\sigma^2_3,\sigma_{12},\sigma_{13}$, you would get

$$\frac{\sigma_{12}\sigma_{13} - \sqrt{(\sigma^2_{1}\sigma^2_2-\sigma_{12}^2)(\sigma^2_{1}\sigma^2_3-\sigma_{13}^2)}}{\sigma^2_1} \le  \sigma_{23} \le \frac{\sigma_{12}\sigma_{13} + \sqrt{(\sigma^2_{1}\sigma^2_2-\sigma_{12}^2)(\sigma^2_{1}\sigma^2_3-\sigma_{13}^2)}}{\sigma^2_1}$$